# Remove "Form" tag with its content from string with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to remove form tag from ajax response content. I have tried below code but it's not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
new Ajax.Request(
  url, {
    method: "post",
    onSuccess: function (b) {
      var a = $("test");

      a.update(b.responseText.replace("[<](/)?form[^>]*[>]", ""));
  }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't look like jQuery to me. It looks like [PrototypeJS](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/ajax/Ajax/Request/).

Comment: Can you share a working snippet using `<>`? Not sure if jquery has `update` at first place.

Comment: @gurvinder372: `update` is also a PrototypeJS thing, like `Ajax.Request`.

Comment: To the OP - Are you using jquery or not? Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Not using jQuery in this answer as the code in your question is clearly using [PrototypeJS](http://prototypejs.org/api) instead.)*

The simplest way is to parse the HTML (the browser is happy to do that for you), remove the `form` element in the result, and then serialize that back to a string (if needed; the browser is happy to do that for you too).

For instance (not using jQuery):

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
// This parses it
div.innerHTML = b.responseText;
// Find and remove the first form; tweak the selector to target if necessary
var form = div.querySelector("form");
if (form) {
    form.parentNode.removeChild(form);
}
// Convert back to string if needed
var str = div.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Remove “Form” tag with its content from string with javascript

Assuming that you meant *Remove “Form” tag along with its content from string*.

If you are using **jquery**, then can try

```
var $bResponseText = $( b.responseText );
$bResponseText.find( "form" ).remove();
b.responseText = $bResponseText[0].outerHTML;
```

Just before using the `update` function

Or another approach with **jquery**

```
$("test").append( b.responseText );
$("test").find( "form" ).last().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple replace the form content with the `<form>`

```js
//detect the form, you can use id or class selector  
var formContent = $('form');
// replace the form with its content so that form tag is removed
formContent.replaceWith(formContent.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='content'>
  <form>
   <div>Content inside Form</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :-

1. Create a temporary div :- `var tempDiv = document.createElement("div");`
2. Then assign response as its innerHTML :- `tempDiv.innerHTML = b.responseText;`
3. After that user querySelectorAll to get all form elements from above temp div :- `var allForms = tempDiv.querySelectorAll("form");`
4. Then iterate over allForms and user remove() method to remove form one by one.
5. After that use tempDiv's innerHTML to get string without form element :- `a.update(tempDiv.innerHTML);`